# add stemming support to CountVectorizer (sklearn)

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

I'm trying to add stemming to my pipeline in NLP with sklearn.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import FrenchStemmer

stop = stopwords.words('french')
stemmer = FrenchStemmer()


class StemmedCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
    def __init__(self, stemmer):
        super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).__init__()
        self.stemmer = stemmer

    def build_analyzer(self):
        analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
        return lambda doc:(self.stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc))

stem_vectorizer = StemmedCountVectorizer(stemmer)
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', stem_vectorizer), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), ('clf', SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)) ])
```

When using this pipeline with the CountVectorizer of sklearn it works. And if I create manually the features like this it works also.

```
vectorizer = StemmedCountVectorizer(stemmer)
vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_counts)
```

**EDIT**:

If I try this pipeline on my IPython Notebook it displays the [*] and nothing happens. When I look at my terminal, it gives this error :

```
Process PoolWorker-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\pool.py", line 360, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StemmedCountVectorizer'
```

*Example*

Here is the complete example

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import grid_search
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from nltk.stem.snowball import FrenchStemmer

stemmer = FrenchStemmer()
analyzer = CountVectorizer().build_analyzer()

def stemming(doc):
    return (stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc))

X = ['le chat est beau', 'le ciel est nuageux', 'les gens sont gentils', 'Paris est magique', 'Marseille est tragique', 'JCVD est fou']
Y = [1,0,1,1,0,0]

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), ('clf', SVC())])
parameters = { 'vect__analyzer': ['word', stemming]}

gs_clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(text_clf, parameters, n_jobs=-1)
gs_clf.fit(X, Y)
```

If you remove stemming from the parameters it works otherwise it doesn't work.

**UPDATE**:

The problem seems to be in the parallelization process because when removing **n_jobs=-1** the problem disappear.

Comment: this seems to be an issue with pickling and unpickling scope. if you put `stemming` in an imported module, for instance, it'll be unpickled more reliably.

Comment: Could you please provide an example or a link to understand what you said ? How to put 'stemming' in an imported module ? Because without the parallelization, the GridSearch is quite slow with a few parameters to tune.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can run your complete example without a problem. But what I meant is to move the code for `stemming` into `myutils.py` for instance, and use `from myutils import stemming`.

Comment: Yes, finally it works. Could you edit your answer so I can accept it ? Because this really was my problem.

Comment: Could you first clarify how you were running the code such that it did not work. Were you entering it into the interactive console, in IDLE, an ipython notebook, running a script, etc...?

Answer (score 34):

You can pass a callable as `analyzer` to the `CountVectorizer` constructor to provide a custom analyzer. This appears to work for me.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.stem.snowball import FrenchStemmer

stemmer = FrenchStemmer()
analyzer = CountVectorizer().build_analyzer()

def stemmed_words(doc):
    return (stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc))

stem_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=stemmed_words)
print(stem_vectorizer.fit_transform(['Tu marches dans la rue']))
print(stem_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Prints out:

```
  (0, 4)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 3)    1
[u'dan', u'la', u'march', u'ru', u'tu']
```

Comment: parameters = { 'vect__analyzer': ['word', stemming]}
Using this as parameters to the gridsearch gives the error :
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stemming'

Comment: If we are overriding the analyzer parameter and it is no longer the default value of 'word'. Are the tokenizer and stopword parameters disabled as mentioned in the documentation here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: In which case is it then needed to be implemented in the same analyzer function?

Answer (score 20):

I know I am little late in posting my answer.
But here it is, in case someone still needs help.

Following is the cleanest approach to add language stemmer to count vectorizer by overriding `build_analyser()`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import nltk.stem

french_stemmer = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('french')
class StemmedCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
    def build_analyzer(self):
        analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
        return lambda doc: ([french_stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc)])

vectorizer_s = StemmedCountVectorizer(min_df=3, analyzer="word", stop_words='french')
```

You can freely call `fit` and `transform` functions of CountVectorizer class over your `vectorizer_s` object

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran this code and the stemmer worked correctly, but the custom stop_words provided under the stop_words arg are no longer working. Is there is a work around?

Comment: @Ramya Yes there is a workaround: from nltk.corpus import stopwords StemmedCountVectorizer(..., stop_words=stopwords.words('french'))

Comment: @ChirazBenAbdelkader this doesn't remove stopwords. As the [documentation explains](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) explains, the `stop_words` argument `Only applies if analyzer == word`

Comment: Should you stem the stopwords before passing them or not? I mean, are the stopwords filtered before or after the analyzer is applied?

Comment: Think I found it (correct me if I'm wrong): [link to code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L75), when added by overriding `build_analyzer`, stemming happens after stopword removal, so it makes no sense to stem the stopwords

Comment: A related question is then, does it make more sense to do stopword removal after stemming? In that case, adding stemming as suggested here may not be the best way

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
def build_analyzer(self):
    analyzer = super(CountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
    return lambda doc:(stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc))
```

and remove the `__init__` method.

Comment: It doesn't work (give the same error) and I need the stemmer attribute.

Comment: Could you give more informations about the error printed ? Which line breaks for instance ?

Comment: I'm using a GridSearch with n_jobs=-1 to parallelize the work.

Comment: The problem is probably due to `lambda` functions not being picklable. Just replace the `lambda` function by a `def` function.