# Are max_df and min_df limits applied after or before stop word removal and finding bigrams in a CountVectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, nltk, n-gram, stop-words, countvectorizer

I am new to nltk. I am trying to understand the order of execution of various parameters in the CountVectorizer.

1. Tokenizing - say, custom tokenizing with removal of words lesser than 3 chars. By default does the CountVextorizer allow hyphenated and underscored words e.g. Aug-2015, GPA 3.9 etc.
2. Handling Upper and Lower Case
3. Removal of stop words
4. Removing words based on document frequency - max_df and min_df
5. Finding bigrams
6. Stemming - if added either as part of custom tokenization defnition or through analyzer as given in this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182502/add-stemming-support-to-countvectorizer-sklearn](http://adding%20stemming%20Countvectorizer)

Comment: Good question!!

Comment: It is done at last step after stop word removal, and finding vocabulary (bigrams). See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775000/3374996) for the working